# Delete third-to-last line of file using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, ed

I have several text files with different row numbers  and I have to delete in all of them  the third-to-last line . Here is a sample file:

```
bear
horse
window
potato
berry
cup
```

Expected result for this file:

```
bear
horse
window
berry
cup
```

Can we delete the third-to-last line of a file:
a. not based on any string/pattern.
b. based only on a condition that it has to be the third-to-last line

I have problem on how to index my files beginning from the last line. I have tried this from another SO question for the second-to-last line:

```
> sed -i 'N;$!P;D' output1.txt
```

Comment: sed is the wrong tool for anything other than `s/old/new/`. If you're using any sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you should be using awk instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tac` + `awk` solution, could you please try following. Just set `line` variable of `awk` to line(from bottom) whichever you want to skip.

```
tac Input_file | awk -v line="3" 'line==FNR{next} 1' | tac
```

***Explanation:*** Using `tac` will read the Input_file reverse(from bottom line to first line), passing its output to `awk` command and then checking condition if line is equal to line(which we want to skip) then don't print that line, 1 will print other lines.

***2nd solution:*** With `awk` + `wc` solution, kindly try following.

```
awk -v lines="$(wc -l < Input_file)" -v skipLine="3" 'FNR!=(lines-skipLine+1)' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Starting `awk` program here and creating a variable `lines` which has total number of lines present in Input_file in it. variable `skipLine` has that line number which we want to skip from bottom of Input_file. Then in main program checking condition if current line is NOT equal to `lines-skipLine+1` then printing the lines.

***3rd solution:*** Adding solution as per Ed sir's comment here.

```
awk -v line=3 '{a[NR]=$0} END{for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (i != (NR-line)) print a[i]}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for 3rd solution.

```
awk -v line=3 '             ##Starting awk program from here, setting awk variable line to 3(line which OP wants to skip from bottom)
{
  a[NR]=$0                  ##Creating array a with index of NR and value is current line.
}
END{                        ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){       ##Starting for loop till value of NR here.
    if(i != (NR-line)){     ##Checking condition if i is NOT equal to NR-line then do following.
      print a[i]            ##Printing a with index i here.
    }
  }
}
' Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: and chances are using an awk variable is overkill and  the OP would be happy with `NR!=3'`

Answer (score 8):

With `ed`

```
ed -s ip.txt <<< $'$-2d\nw'

# thanks Shawn for a more portable solution
printf '%s\n' '$-2d' w | ed -s ip.txt
```

This will do in-place editing. `$` refers to last line and you can specify a negative relative value. So, `$-2` will refer to last but second line. `w` command will then write the changes.

See [ed: Line addressing](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Line-addressing) for more details.

Comment: I love seeing people besides me using `ed` in answers. It **will** be a thing again! (Though I'd use `printf '%s\n' '$-2d' w | ed -s ip.txt` instead of relying on bashisms)

Comment: @Shawn all those posts have made an impression on me, I think this is the first I've tried it out for a SO answer.. I'll likely try to learn more about it and write a blog post

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1N;N;$!P;D' file
```

Open a window of 3 lines in the file then print/delete the first line of the window until the end of the file.

At the end of the file, do not print the first line in the window i.e. the 3rd line from the end of the file. Instead, delete it, and repeat the sed cycle. This will try to append a line after the end of file, which will cause sed to bail out, printing the remaining lines in the window.

A generic solution for n lines back (where n is 2 or more lines from the end of the file), is:

```
sed ':a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/3;Ta;$!P;D' file
```

Of course you could use:

```
tac file | sed 3d | tac
```

But then you would be reading the file 3 times.

Comment: For a large input, `tac | sed '3d' | tac` will be faster than `sed '1N;N;$!P;D' file` (tested) while the command group of head and tail (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049387/7589636)  will be multiple times faster because it doesn't really read the lines but `seek()` for the line number and dump the content. Similar to this, `tac` is like `cat`, means fast, also `sed '3d'` is following, but sed folding lines will read and write the same lines again, for all the input.

Answer (score 2):

To delete the 3rd-to-last line of a file, you can use `head` and `tail`:

```
{ head -n -3 file; tail -2 file; }
```

In case of a large input file, when perfomance matters, this is very fast, because it doesn't read and write line by line. Also, do not modify the semicolons and the spaces next to the brackets, see about [commands grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html).

---

Or use `sed` with `tac`:

```
tac file | sed '3d' | tac
```

---

Or use `awk` with `tac`:

```
tac file | awk 'NR!=3' | tac
```